# Why App server memory is not being released even after completing the load test in silk performer?

Tags: jboss6.x, silk-performer

I am doing the load test of 150 users when we saw memory utilization of app server through vmstat command. it is showing that memory is not being released but after restart of App server it gets released. Even by monitoring through Dynatrace tool memory is getting releases but not showing on putty (vmstat).

[image]

App server : Jboss

Where is the problem?

Comment: What kind of behaviour are the virtual users running? Are they creating some kind of session in the server? Is it that session logged off?

Comment: Yes there is databse intervention, some sql quries getting fired.
We are doing loadtest of API module with 150 users before starting the loadtest overall RAM memory is 20GB from that 4GB is assigned to this API module. After that we start the loadtest & during loadtest both free physical memory(it is getting reduced from 7GB to 4GB) as well as heap memory(it is utilized from 1GB to 2GB). When we stop the loadtest heap memory is getting released but not the free physical memory.